# C# Type Casting at Runtime for Array.SetValue

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection, casting, runtime

I'm trying to create an array using reflection, and insert values into it.  I'm trying to do this for many different types so would like a `createAndFillArray` function capable of this :

```
String propertyName1 = "prop1";
String propertyName2 = "prop2";

Type t1 = typeof(myType).getProperty(propertyName1).PropertyType.getElementType();
Type t2 = typeof(myType).getProperty(propertyName2).PropertyType.getElementType();

double exampleA = 22.5;
int exampleB = 43;

Array arrA = createAndFillArray(t1, exampleA);
Array arrB = createAndFillArray(t2, exampleB);

private Array createAndFillArray(Type t, object val){
    Array arr = Array.CreateInstance( t, 1); //length 1 in this example only, real-world is of variable length.
    arr.SetValue( val, 0 ); //this causes the following error: "System.InvalidCastException : Object cannot be stored in an array of this type."
    return arr;
}
```

with the class A being as follows:

```
public class A{
    public A(){}

    private double val;
    public double Value{
        get{ return val; }
        set{ this.val = value; }
    }

    public static implicit operator A(double d){
        A a = new A();
        a.Value = d;
        return a;
    }
}
```

and class B being very similar, but with `int`:

```
public class B{
    public B(){}

    private double val;
    public double Value{
        get{ return val; }
        set{ this.val = value; }
    }

    public static implicit operator B(double d){
        B b = new B();
        b.Value = d;
        return b;
    }
}
```

and myType is something like the following:

```
public class myType{
    public A prop1{ get; set; }
    public B prop2{ get; set; }
}
```

I hoped that the implicit operator would have ensured that the double be converted to class A, or the int to class B, and the error avoided; but this is obviously not so.

The above is used in a custom deserialization class, which takes data from a custom data format and fills in the corresponding .Net object properties.  I'm doing this via reflection and at runtime, so I think both are unavoidable.  I'm targeting the C# 2.0 framework.

I've dozens, if not hundreds, of classes similar to `A` and `B`, so would prefer to find a solution which improved on the `createAndFillArray` method rather than a solution which altered these classes.

Comment: Why do not using `public class X<T>` instead of same class just different member types?

Comment: [Implicit conversions have to be resolved at compile-time.](http://philosopherdeveloper.wordpress.com/2010/05/05/the-difference-between-converting-and-unboxing-read-my-mind-compiler/) An unboxing operation will not magically perform an implicit conversion when the compiler couldn't have known the types ahead of time. The same rule applies to all method overload resolution cases.

Comment: @Saeed that would be best, but unfortunately the classes A, B, C etc.. are legacy and I'm very unwilling to go about changing them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's [an example](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/903775-getting-operators-using-reflection) of using reflection to find the conversion method.  So if you can get that method on your type and do the conversion your self.

Copied from: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/903775-getting-operators-using-reflection

```
//EndType is the type I want to PRODUCE
//StartType is the type I am pulling data FROM
MethodInfo mi = EndType.GetMethod(
    "op_Implicit", 
    (BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static), 
    null, 
    new Type[] { StartType }, 
    new ParameterModifier[0]
);
//Now if mi is NOT null, it means there is an operator that allows for converting StartType to EndType, if it is null, there isn't one
```

Answer (score 2):

Casting is resolved at compile time, which in your case would be looking at at the type of the first parameter to `Array.SetValue` which is of type `object`, the 0 will be cast to type `object` (ie. boxed).

Is there a reason that you need to use reflection? As others have posted you can do this with generics.

Here is an approximation of your reflection code using generics

```
private T[] createAndFillArray<T>(T val)
{
  T[] array = new T[1];
  array[0] = val;
  return array;      
}
```

Which you can call as follows

```
Array arrA = createAndFillArray<A>(exampleA);
Array arrB = createAndFillArray<B>(exampleB);
```

Based on your comment one possible implementation might be

```
private Array createAndFillArray(Type t, string property, object val)
{
  object element = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
  PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty(property);
  if (pi != null)
  {
    pi.SetValue(element, val, null);
  }

  Array arr = Array.CreateInstance(t, 1);
  arr.SetValue(element, 0);
  return arr;
}
```

Which you can use as follows

```
Array arrB = createAndFillArray(t2, "Value", exampleB);
```

Where "Value" is the name of the property in the target type that you want to set.

Comment: I'm determining the type by reflection at runtime.  I have a string for the property name, which I'm using PropertyInfo pi = myType.getProperty(propertyName).  The pi.PropertyType is the type of array I wish to create.  I'm not sure if generics will help with this case...

Comment: @sprocketonline, I understand. We probably need more info on the problem scope. Is the value always a double value, do all the classes have a property called Value etc. Because you could dynamically create the instance, set the property value and added the instance in the array all this in the call to createAndFillArray, but more info is required to understand if this is just a simplification of your real problem or the real scope of the problem.

Comment: The above is a large simplification of the real problem.  The 'Value' property PropertyType can be of any type (all value types, custom classes, the lot) and the property is not always known as 'Value'.  However, there is/should always be a public static implicit operator for the conversion, so I've started implementing shf301's solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

First, generics would make the array creation trivial:

```
public static T[] CreateAndFill<T>(params T[] values)
{
    var retval = new T[values.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        retval[i] = values[i];
    return retval;
}
```

Second, one reason why your implicit casts aren't working could be because the method you're using to set the value in the array actually ends in an `extern` call (into what library I can't tell via Reflector), which most likely doesn't check for the implicit conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work...

```
private Array createAndFillArray<T>(object val){
    Array arr = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(t), 1); //length 1 in this example only, real-world is of variable length.
    arr.SetValue( (T)val, 0 ); //this causes the following error: "System.InvalidCastException : Object cannot be stored in an array of this type."
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: This will not work because for one thing when you un-box the value it must be unboxed to the exact same type, so a boxed double must be unboxed to a double, here you will be trying to unbox a double to type A to type B which is invalid.